# Expose random port to docker-compose.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I need multiple instance of same application, for that I am using 
`server.port=0` to run application in random port. 
my question is how can I map randomly generated port to docker-compose.yml to create multiple instances. 
I am using spring boot at the back-end. I am unable to find any solution. 
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Each Docker container runs a single process in an isolated network namespace, so this isn't necessary.  Pick a fixed port.  For HTTP services, common port numbers include 80, 3000, 8000, and 8080, depending on permissions and the language runtime (80 requires elevated privileges, 3000 is Node's default, and so on).  The exact port number doesn't matter.

You access the port from outside Docker space using a published port.  If you're running multiple containers, there is the potential for conflict if multiple services use the same host port, which is probably what you're trying to avoid.  In the [`docker run -p`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) option or the Docker Compose [`ports:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) setting, it's possible to list only the port running inside the container, and Docker will choose a host port for you.

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: ...
    ports:
      - "8000"                       # no explicit host port
    command: ... -Dserver.port=8000  # fixed container port
```

[`docker-compose port`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/port/) `web 8000` will tell you what the host (public) port number is.  For communication between containers in the same `docker-compose.yml` file, you can use the service name and the (fixed, known) internal port, `http://web:8000`.

Comment: I can communicate with container within docker-compose file using fixed port for container and exposing them for host machine. server.port=0 generate random port on run time. Is there any way we can expose that randomly generated port to host machine?

Comment: No, the Docker port mapping mechanism wants a fixed port inside the container.  Since each container runs in an isolated network environment there's no need to randomize the port.

Comment: I am new to docker. I am little bit confused here now. If we make port fix, while we crate multiple instance, there may be port binding problem. How multiple instances can be created while port is made fixed?

Comment: "will tell you what the host (public) port number is." Im not seeing this in the output. Where does it tell me this?